# Hey how can I make values [1] bold on the email and how could i change the colour of the text?

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is the script. I would like to know how to add bold text and also how to change the colour of the text in the email. I'm also interested in knowing how to pull the cell directly into the email with the original formatting of the spreadsheet.

Thanks!

```
function myAlerts() { // this runs based on daily trigger
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Campaign List");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();   var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
  var curDate = values[1][11];
  var anyMatches = false;
  var message = "";   var sheetUrl = ss.getUrl();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var optionalEmail = values[2][12]; 
  if (optionalEmail != "") { email = email + "," + optionalEmail; }
  for (var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++) {
    // if today matches the alert date, send an alert
    if (values[i][5].toString() == curDate.toString()) {  
      // add a message for this row if date matches
      message = message + values[i][1] + " will expire on " + values[i][5] + "<br />\n";
      // if there is a match, set anyMatches to true so and email gets sent
      anyMatches = true;
    }
  }  // ends for loop
  // footer for message
  message = message +  "<br />\nThis is an auto-generated email to remind you of your campaign expiration. <br />\n"
  if (anyMatches)  { // send an email   
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: 'Campaign Expiration Notice!',
      htmlBody: message});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myAlerts() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Campaign List");
  var range=sheet.getDataRange();   
  var values=range.getDisplayValues();
  var lastRow=range.getLastRow();
  var curDate=values[1][11];
  var anyMatches=false;
  var message="";
  var sheetUrl=ss.getUrl();
  var email=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var optionalEmail=values[2][12]; 
  if (optionalEmail!=""){
    email+="," + optionalEmail; 
  }
  for (var i=1;i<lastRow;i++) {
    if (values[i][5].toString()==curDate.toString()) {
      message+=Utilities.formatString('<strong>%s</strong> will expire on %s <br />\n"',values[i][1],values[i][5]);
      anyMatches=true;
    }
  }  
  message+='<br />\n<font color="red">This is an auto-generated email to remind you of your campaign expiration.</font><br />\n'
  if (anyMatches)  {
    MailApp.sendEmail({to: email,subject: 'Campaign Expiration Notice!',htmlBody: message});
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! But I received an error "Missing ] in index expression. (line 18"

Comment: Yes. I messed up one of the brackets.  It's fixed now.

Comment: I noticed there was an extra '[' next to the [5]. I removed it - all good. Thanks!